# iOS ViewController bounds using the same bounds as device from Xcode Interface Builder

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ipad, bounds

I'm designing an app storyboard free, I have this code in the App Delegate which sets the window's root view controller:

```
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    let loginVC = LoginViewController()
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: loginVC)

    self.window!.rootViewController = navigationController
    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

But for some reason when the login view controller loads, it looks like this:
[image: iPad Screenshot]

I'm setting a gradient with the frame of the view controller's bounds like this:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(gradientStyle: .diagonal, withFrame: self.view.bounds, andColors: [
            firstColor!,
            secondColor!
])
```

And as you can see in the screenshot, the gradient just repeats itself. I had some elements such as buttons that were also getting clipped off as the gradient repeated itself. So I changed the Xib device to an iPad in the Xcode IB and the gradient still repeated itself but not as much. I've been dealing with this for 3 days now so I'm finally giving up and posting it on StackOverflow.

Thank you sooooo much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you setting your gradient color in `viewDidLoad()`?

It that's the case, `self.view.bounds` is still the size in your storyboard view, and you will need to wait before setting your gradient color.

`viewDidAppear(_:)` will be at least 1 frame too late, so my piece of advice is to call it inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` but keep in mind it might be called more than once:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(gradientStyle: .diagonal, withFrame: self.view.bounds, andColors: [
        firstColor!,
        secondColor!
    ])
}
```

Comment: You're a life-saver!

Comment: Happy to help! ;)